# Angular2 testing logic before .subscribe

Tags: unit-testing, angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-testing

I am currently writing unit tests for one of my components. In particular, I have `login(): void` function. Here's the simplified logic:

```
login(): void {
  this.showSpinner = true;
  this.userService.login(loginData)
    .subscribe(result => {
      this.showSpinner = false;
    }
  )
}
```

I am struggling to write a test that checks that `showSpinner` property gets set to `true` before calling the `userService.login`.

Here's my test:

```
it('should display the spinner when the form is being saved',
  inject([TestComponentBuilder], fakeAsync((tcb: any) => {
    createComponent(tcb).then((fixture:ComponentFixture<any>) => {
      fixture.componentInstance.login();
      expect(fixture.componentInstance.showSpinner).toBe(true);
      tick();
    });
  })));
});
```

And this test fails, because `.subscribe` gets resolved / run immediately (i tried commenting out `this.showSpinner = false` in my component, and the test passed).

In my `userService` mock, I have the following, for the `login` method mock:

`this.loginSpy = this.spy('login').andReturn(Observable.of(this));`

Where `this` is `mockUserService`.

I am confident that I am mocking `userService` and specifically the `login` method on the `userService` correctly, as I have other tests for this component that behave correctly.

I have also tried returning `Observable.of(this).delay(1)` from my spy and then calling `tick(1)` in my test. However that results in inconsistent behaviour in that sometimes my tests pass, but other times i get an error saying:

`Error: 1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue.`

How can I test the logic that precedes `.subscribe()`?

Answer (score 0):

After more consideration I have realized that my current code does not abide by the single responsibility principle. This thought came from the fact that everyone is always repeating that you should "Refactor hard to test code".

With that in mind, I have moved all the logic that needed to be done before the call to `userService.login` is being made - into its own separate function. Which essentially results in:

```
login():void {
  this.userService.login(this.loginData)
    .subscribe(result => {
       this.showSpinner = false;
    });
}

formSubmit(): void {
  this.showSpinner = true;
  this.login();
}
```

This logic is now much easier to test.

**HOWEVER** we need to remember to add a spy on our `login()` method when we are testing `formSubmit()`, as if we don't, `formSubmit()` will simply make a call to `login()`, which will again complete synchronously and we will have the same problem. So my new and final test for this feature is:

```
it('should display the spinner when the form is being saved',
  inject([TestComponentBuilder], fakeAsync((tcb: any) => {
    createComponent(tcb).then((fixture:ComponentFixture<any>) => {
      var loginSpy = spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, 'login');
      fixture.componentInstance.formSubmit();
      expect(fixture.componentInstance.showSpinner).toBe(true);
    });
  })));
});
```